# Self exponential quadratic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Consider the equation

$$(x^2+4x+5)^{(x^2+4x+5)^{(x^2+4x+5)}} = 2018$$

Find the sum of real values of $x$.

Comment: Are you asking for help with this? Have you tried something yourself? Perhaps you can make a variable change ...

Comment: $(z^z)^z$ or $z^{(z^z)}$ ?

Answer (score 4):

As $z^{z^z}$ is a strictly growing function, there is a single root to $$z^{z^z}=2018,$$ let $z_0$.

Then by Vieta the sum of the roots of

$$x^2+4x+5=z_0$$ is $-4$.

Comment: (+) sorry I was in a hurry and did not understand the required well